# What is a signed Android App Bundles AAB?

Tags: android, android-build, android-bundle, bitrise, android-signing

I first see this notion "signed Android App Bundles AAB" on Bitrise.
Can someone explain to me what is an signed AAB ?
I only know: signed APK, unsigned APK and AAB.
Thank you.

Comment: It is the *"new"* [Android App Bundles](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle)

Comment: In the most basic terms, Its the same as a signed APK but instead it is a SIgned AAB so its a certified/signed AAB

Comment: if `signingConfig` is set, `bundleRelease` task will output a signed aab ?

Comment: Android App Bundles is a fantastic way to do apps, whilst it can have some signing benefits the real major difference I found was the way it deals with splitting APKs. Bundles deals with this for you completely, which allows for your app to have less resources, run a tiny bit faster, install faster and just be a smaller installed APK size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are unsigned AAB and signed AAB.
I did not understand that we can sign an AAB.